# Is it possible to recreate a pyqtgraph without data

Tags: pyqt5, pyqtgraph

I have a pyqt5 based application where I open a file and plot 2 different plots based on the data from the file. Now I want to open another similar file, but I want to save the status/view of the 2 plots, so that I could come quickly back to the previous plots/views, without having to plot it again by reading the data. Is it possible at all to save the state/view of the plots to recreate it very quickly?

Answer (score -1):

You can guide from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65428979/13929529) .

Basically, you can use the `PlotWidget` class from `pyqtgraph`.

- Generate a `PlotWidget`.

  ```
  import pyqtgraph as pg
  plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
  ```
- Use the `plot()` method and store the `PlotDataItem` in a variable. The `PlotDataItem` will contain the information of that specific plot: x-data, y-data, the color of the line, the line width, ...

  ```
  plot_item = plot_widget.plot(xData, yData)
  ```
- With this you can add/remove the item from the plot every time you want with the `addItem()` and `removeItem()` methods

  ```
  plot_widget.removeItem(plot_item)
  plot_widget.addItem(plot_item)
  ```

## EDIT:

To get the view state of the plot, you can use the `viewRect()` method of the `PlotWidget` class. It will return a `QRectF` object which contains the information of the view state like this:

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QRectF(x_0, y_0, w, h)
```

Where:

- `x_0` and `y_0` are the coordinates where the view starts.
- `w` and `h` are the width and height of the view area.

Also, you can restore the view using the `setRange()` method of the `PlotWidget` class.

### Example:

Here is an example of the implementation of this:

```py
import sys
import numpy as np
import pyqtgraph as pg
from pyqtgraph.Qt import QtGui

class MyApp(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
    
        self.central_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.buttons_layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.boxes_layout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout()
        self.save = QtGui.QPushButton('Save View')
        self.set = QtGui.QPushButton('Set View')
        self.boxes = [QtGui.QCheckBox(f"Box {i+1}") for i in range(3)]
        self.plot_widget = pg.PlotWidget()
        self.plot_data = [None for _ in range(3)]
        self.state = [False for _ in range(3)]
        
        self.setLayout(self.central_layout)
        self.central_layout.addWidget(self.plot_widget)
        self.central_layout.addLayout(self.buttons_layout)
        self.buttons_layout.addLayout(self.boxes_layout)
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.save)
        self.buttons_layout.addWidget(self.set)
        for i in range(3):
            self.boxes_layout.addWidget(self.boxes[i])
            self.boxes[i].stateChanged.connect(self.box_changed)
        self.create_data()
        
        self.save.clicked.connect(self.save_view)
        self.set.clicked.connect(self.set_view)
        self.view_state = None
        self.save_view()
            
    def create_data(self):
        x = np.linspace(0, 3.14, 100)
        y = [np.sin(x), np.cos(x), np.sin(x)**2]
        for i in range(3):
            self.plot_data[i] = pg.PlotDataItem(x, y[i])

    def box_changed(self):
        for i in range(3):
            if self.boxes[i].isChecked() != self.state[i]:
                self.state[i] = self.boxes[i].isChecked()
                if self.state[i]:
                    if self.plot_data[i] is not None:
                        self.plot_widget.addItem(self.plot_data[i])
                    else:
                        self.plot_data[i] = self.plot_widget.plot(*self.box_data[i])
                else:
                    self.plot_widget.removeItem(self.plot_data[i])
                break
    
    def save_view(self):
        self.view_state = self.plot_widget.viewRect()
     
    def set_view(self):
        self.plot_widget.setRange(self.view_state)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Your question clearly doesn't answer what the OP asks. The OP's question is how to save and restore the state of a plot, for example after the initial plot is shown then the user zooms and then closes the window, and when the application will open then the plot must have the same zoom as had before closing the window. How does your answer cover that problem?

Comment: addItem and removeItem doesnt help me recreate the same plot view as @eyllanesc mentioned.

Comment: @saras Sorry I was out for two weeks. I edited the answer, and now it satisfies the request you made.

Comment: @eyllanesc You were right, I edited my answer